# Removing characters preceded by an exact number of spaces

Tags: python, regex

```
-9999     840  0 1300  0 1410  0 1890  0 2140  0 2420  0 2640  0 2500  0 1990  0 1410  0    0  0
```

I would like to remove the `0`s which are preceded by **exactly two spaces** using `regular expressions`. How could I go about it?

Comment: `re.sub(r"(\s\s0)\b", '', string)` ?

Comment: `a.replace('  0','')` you will get `'-9999     840 1300 1410 1890 2140 2420 2640 2500 1990 1410  '`

Comment: @Ch3steR not if one of the numbers starts with a leading 0

Comment: @Frieder Good point.

Comment: @Frieder `' '.join(a.split('  0 '))` is giving correct answer.

Comment: @Felix if not regex you can use `' '.join(a.split('  0 '))`.

Answer (score 2):

Using `re.sub` with pattern `\b(\s\s0)\b`

```
import re

s = "-9999     840  0 1300  0 1410  0 1890  0 2140  0 2420  0 2640  0 2500  0 1990  0 1410  0    0  0"
print(re.sub(r"\b(\s\s0)\b", '', s))   
# --> -9999     840 1300 1410 1890 2140 2420 2640 2500 1990 1410    0
```

Comment: what does \b do?

Comment: `\b` --> word boundary

Comment: sorry, I'm still fairly new to python. what specifically does a word boundary do?

Answer (score 1):

I would write your requirement as:

```
inp = '-9999     840  0 1300  0 1410  0 1890  0 2140  0 2420  0 2640  0 2500  0 1990  0 1410  0    0  0'
out = re.sub(r'(?<\S)[ ]{2}0', '', inp)
print(out)
```

This prints:

```
-9999     840 1300 1410 1890 2140 2420 2640 2500 1990 1410    0
```

The positive lookbehind `(?<=\S)` will match a boundary being another character or the start of the entire input.  This could be important should some of your inputs open with two spaces followed by a zero.

Comment: `' '.join(a.split(' 0 '))` can also be used if not for regex.